# Do you make an audiotape with or by a tape recorder?

Tags: prepositions

Do you make an audiotape with or by a tape recorder? It's a tool, isn't it? Should I use 'with'? I have a suspicion that I shouldn't but can't tell why.

Comment: You make a recording **with** a tape recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little odd, because saying that one made an audiotape with a tape recorder sounds a little redundant -- how else would one make an audiotape?

If we can change the example slightly to name a brand of tape recorder, I think it makes more sense:

```
This is a tape made by a Nagra recorder.
This is a tape made with a Nagra recorder.
```

Both of those are correct, and mean the same thing. The first one might carry an (incorrect) implication that the recorder did the recording by itself, instead of being operated by someone, but that doesn't make any sense and so would be understood to mean the same as the second sentence.

Comment: I could add made **on** a _Brand_ recorder.